# Chrome extension launch function before switching/closing tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've made a small test chrome extension that allows me to display a div on the active tab when I press ctrl+space, and it remove that div when I press again.
Currently, the divs stays on the pages I placed it when I switch tab.

I'd like to be able to remove the div when I change tab, so when I come back, it's not there anymore.

I've tried this :

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(obj){
    if($("#popin").length>=1){
      $("#popin").remove();
        alert("change");
    }
});
```

But it doesn't do anything.
I also tried the same without conditions, and it keeps sending me the alert when I switch tabs. 
How could I make it work with my condition please ?

Comment: chrome.tabs.onActivated should be used in the background page, which is a separate page, not related to the web page (see the extension architecture in the documentation). You can save active tabId in a global variable or a chrome.storage.local in the background page so that onActivated callback can send a message to that tab's content script to remove the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just fine. But is that normal that the div is being removed only when I switch back to the tab where I opened it ?
I open it on tab A, switch to tab B, background do executeScript on tab A to remove my div, but I it's really removed only when I switch back to tab A. Am I doing something wrong or is it normal ?